# steps to debug a dll used in an mvc 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll

I have a dll project and an mvc 5 project

I want to debug the dll project when it is used in the mvc project

I already built the dll project in debug mode and they work if I put these generated debug files directly in the bin folder of the mvc 5 project

but now I want to debug the dll code when the mvc project calls it, without moving files around, what are the exact steps to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build the dll project in debug mode, take the generated files and put them in the bin folder of the MVC project

In my case the dll uses c++ code -> unmanaged code, so in VS MVC project

right click project name->properties->web->Debuggers check the "Native code"

save the project, put the breakpoint, run in debug mode, VS will show "debugging information for iisexpress.exe cannot be found..." continue debugging

Now I can step inside the dll code

Answer (score 0):

Open VS or your debugger and attach to w3wp.exe and ensure you have your DLL's symbols loaded. That's all you need to do.

Comment: I will like if you could describe it more from the state I am at. I have the two projects, and I have build the dll project, I haven't moved any dll files around, do I have to? In the mvc project I have all the necessary code for the dll to work, but this works only when I have the dll directly in the mvc->bin folder, do I need to leave the dll there to debug its code?

Comment: @Wusevari yes, all DLLs must be in the `bin` directory. I suggest you read-up on debugging in .NET and IIS.

Comment: I have tried this, first I leave the dll in the bin folder, I run the mvc project "start without debugging", In my dll project I put my breakpoint and I click on "debug"->"attach to process" there is no "w3wp.exe" so I attached to iisexpress.exe, then in my webpage I go to the link that triggers the dll method but it's not hitting the breakpoint in the dll project, what am I missing?

Comment: @Wusevari your question is beyond the scope of StackOverflow and I cannot help you further, sorry.

Comment: I will keep trying, I am sure the steps are simple, I will update question with answer when I get that working